# Rendering more than one RadioButton.Group in react native cannot be treated separately

Tags: javascript, react-native

in my application i have two arrays as follow:

```
const items =[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "groupId": 1,
        "name": "product1",
        "price": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "groupId": 1,
        "name": "product2",
        "price": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "groupId": 2,
        "name": "product3",
        "price": 10
    },
    {
        "id": 4,
        "groupId": 2,
        "name": "product4",
        "price": 10
    }
];


  const category = [
        {
            "name": "optional",
            "id": 1,
            "type": 1
        },
        {
            "name": "required",
            "id": 2,
            "type": 1
        },
    ]
```

So, what I am doing I take the category name from array `category` then after displaying the name of category I am rendering the item that belong to that category from the `items` array when `category.id = items.groupId`
I did the following to achieve that:

```
 {items.filter(product => product.groupId === category.id).map(b => {

   return (<View >
              <RadioButton.Group
                  key={b.groupId}
                  value={value}
                  onValueChange={value => { addToOrder(value) }}
                                        
                >
                <View>
                     <RadioButton.Item
                         key={b.id}
                         mode='android'
                         label={b.name}
                         value={b}
                      />
                       <Text>${b.price}</Text>
                 </View>
               </RadioButton.Group>
            </View>
        )
     })
 }
```

So the result was as expected it gave two groups of radio buttons

> ```
> Results looks like: 
> [ ] refer to the circle of the button
> optional
>   - porduct1 $10  [ ] 
>   - porduct2 $10  [ ]  
>  
> required
>   - porduct3 $10  [ ] 
>   - porduct4 $10  [ ]
> ```

However,
the problem I am facing is that  when i check on of the item in the first group and then i check another item in the second group the value in first group is unchecked. I spent several hours trying to solve it but I'm unable to make it work.
the library for radioButtons is  `RadioButton`  `from 'react-native-paper';`

I will appreciate any help. thanks

Comment: is the label={b.name}, same for both the groups? I mean when you inspect the elements

Comment: value={b} here what would be the valye for the radiobutton option?

Comment: @Bharat  `value={b}`  it is the value of the object data in the `items` array, `label={b.name},` it is the name come from items array as well which different not same its values could be one of (product1, product2, product3, product4

Comment: @Bharat yes exactly  the name property it goes for the  `RadioButton.Item` i also edited the question i added how the results looks like

Comment: Is it possible to post rendered HTML from inspect for both the radio button or can you create a simple sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-haze-26usm?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @Bharat Ii have created one in expo as sandbox not supporting react. native please check it out here https://snack.expo.dev/OUQFm72m2

Comment: is the sandbox working? I am not able to see output

Comment: @Bharat sorry for that check sandbox here https://codesandbox.io/embed/crazy-jennings-5f9tg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark it is working, check the console log

Comment: apologies for asking again, I am looking for working example so that i can see how DOM is creating HTML and that will help us undestand why it's behaving that way?

Comment: @Bharat this is working example https://codesandbox.io/embed/crazy-jennings-5f9tg?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @Bharat and this working example in expo it is working foe web as well https://snack.expo.dev/xieHw4ebl